# Git Pull Not Syncing Local Files

Tags: git, local, pull

I've set up my repository in Git. I can commit to it just fine and dandy.

However, when I make changes to my files (git status shows modifications), and I want to pull my repository and overwrite those files that have been changed (just as a test to see if I'm updating my local side correctly), it tells me that my local repo is "Already up-to-date".

From my understanding, I've made changes to my local so it shouldn't be telling me that my local is "up-to-date".

Now the question is, is Git telling me this because I am the same user that last committed to the repo? So if I were, for example, to commit something using my roommate's username, then if I were to pull from mine after his commit, then my local files would be updated?

I know that there are reset commands and revert commands in case that you screwed up or want to revert to your old files on YOUR machine, which is why I think that me being 'the same user' is the problem. Git just doesn't want to pull from the repo because I can reset my changes locally?

Am I on the right track with committing on different users to ACTUALLY pull from the repo?

P.S. - I did set my e-mail and username using the git config --global command (should I have used --local or --system?). Might that be another cause of the problem?

Comment: Did you add and commit the files locally?

Comment: I did add and commit the files locally using: git add --all and then git commit -m "Message for testing" and finally git push. All my commits work fine, I just can't pull the whole repo as I should, and overwrite my local files normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no new conmit in the repo that "touches" the files you have modified there is no change because git understand that you are working locally in this files and (for the moment) there is no conflict with any other modification coming from the repo.

If you want to undo your changes you need to use checkout:

```
git checkout filepath
```

Comment: Well the problem I was having was that I would commit a set of files, change one of them locally and then try to pull the repo to overwrite the local files. It was telling me that everything was up to date, because on the local side, there are options for reversion. 

However, I just tested it with my roommate's computer, setting up his username and all that, and pushing/pulling the repo. Now it works fine. So the conflict, as I thought initially, was that Git wouldn't actually pull the repo because I was still under the same username and thus it thought "oh, do local reversions instead."

Comment: Thank you for your responses though, Jack Maney and @FerCa. I have it working - the conflict was with same remote user credentials and the already existing reversion options on the local side.

If anyone else runs across this problem, you need to use local commands for reversion of your own changes within the last commit by (you), and if you want to test the repository functionality, you need to use two separate credentials for committing/pulling files.